# Why is not componentDidUpdate() called by this code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Code**

```js
const Index = {
  screen: IndexScreen,
  params: { category: null },
};

const IndexStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Index,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Index',
    navigationOptions: {
    ...
    },
  },
);
```

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Index', { category: 1})}
>
  <Text>Navigating to Index</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Product.js**

```js
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log(prevProps.navigation.state.params);
}
```

**Problem**

When navigating to Index from other component, it passes a param : category.

Index should receive it, but `console.log()` in `componentDidUpdate()` returns nothing.

Comment: why set async for componentDidUpate()? i think delete `preveProps` and wirte this : `console.log(props.navigation.state.params)`

Comment: @Thanks. I tried it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should get the navigation params in `componentDidMount`
As you can see here, `componentDidUpdate` gets triggered *after* the rendering, so it won't work when you first start this component.